# How to get output to the table with header?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps

This is my Google Maps API Matrix Distance result:

```
{
'destination_addresses': 3 locations
'origin_addresses': one static location
'rows': [{
    'elements': [{
        'distance': {'text': '0.5 km', 'value': 532}, 
        'duration': {'text': '8 mins', 'value': 452}, 
        'status': 'OK'}, {

        'distance': {'text': '0.7 km', 'value': 682}, 
        'duration': {'text': '9 mins', 'value': 561}, 
        'status': 'OK'}, {

        'distance': {'text': '0.6 km', 'value': 646}, 
        'duration': {'text': '9 mins', 'value': 539}, 
        'status': 'OK'
        }]
       }], 
 'status': 'OK'
}
```

I wrote this to extract 'value' for each distance and duration elements.

```
matrixDistance = gmaps.distance_matrix(origin, destinations, mode = "walking")
split = matrixDistance['rows'][0]['elements']
for a in split:
    distance = a['distance']['value']
    duration = a['duration']['value']
print(distance, duration)
```

My question is how do I print my output in a table, and with the header like this (I can extract the result and a bit clueless how to get the header part):

```
Distance    Duration
     532         452
     682         561
     646         539
```

** I think I can get the value straightaway by coding like below but I kept getting errors. So I split into two parts as shown above:

```
for a in matrixDistance:
    distance = a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value']
    duration = a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']

    print(distance, duration)
```

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

It would be nice if I can clean the code a bit but for now the split part is good but I cannot get the result into a table with header. Is there anybody can give me help on this? Thanks!

*** I also don't know why but my `csv` module is missing. Can't import the module.

Comment: To create a table out of it, i suggest you to use pandas, because IT'S MUCH EASIER!!!

Comment: @U8-Forward I have tried but could not get it distance = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(matrixDistance['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'])

Comment: IMO if you can't `import csv` it sounds like your Python installation is messed up—and it would be very worthwhile to fix that because who knows what other issues it may cause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to this problem. You can find many approaches via different libraries.

```
matrixDistance = gmaps.distance_matrix(origin, destinations, mode = "walking")
split = matrixDistance['rows'][0]['elements']
print("Distance \t Duration")

for a in split:
    distance = a['distance']['value']
    duration = a['duration']['value']
    print("{} \t\t {}".format(distance ,duration))
```

Comment: Thank you @Lasith Niroshan. From there on, is it possible to save both into a csv?

Comment: yes, of course, you can import CSV library then you can whatever thing you want.